# Is this a picture of Ted Cruz as a mime?

Tags: united-states, politics

[image: Ted Cruz as a mime]

Caption reads,

> Ted Cruz played Adam in a mime performance of the Christian creation story when he was in high school. Is this really the fight that he wants to have?

I've seen this picture now many times. This time [I found here](https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1405897-ted-cruz-mime-photoshops), but it seems to be pretty hot on Facebook. Where is this picture from and is it legit?

Comment: May I (as European interested in U.S politics and culture) ask why this is contentious or in other ways important and why Ted Cruz would potentially fight over it?

Comment: What fight? ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The meme in OP's question says "is this really the fight that he wants to have". I, too, am curious about the context. I can't think of many things this would be relevant to - Cruz hasn't, to my knowledge, bashed mimes recently or anything...

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It seems to mean a meme fight: https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/ted-cruz-mime-meme_us_5b876ff7e4b0cf7b00320ae0

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider The venue matters: Texas. Ted Cruz is betting on out-stereotyping Beto O'Rourke in the realm of gun-toting, independence-loving, rough-and-tumble lifestyle. Beto O'Rourke was a punk kid who left Texas to create a technology company, and Cruz wants to paint O'Rourke as an outsider to Texan values. As such, he posted pictures of Beto in a punk band and a mugshot from a DUI 20 years ago.

Comment: ...and this is a fantastic example of Poe's Law... because a fair number of those Texas voters would look at this, and think that "lead role in a biblically literal mime rendition of the Garden of Eden story" was actually pretty endearing.  Their censure instead would fall on those suggesting that it was un-Texan... and on O'Rourke by extension.  So... who's supporters produced this?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider US politics is so toxic that people will pick on anything a politician does that is in any way unusual and try to make fun of it.

Comment: @BenBarden Don't tell me they are enacting a literal Garden of Eden story *with clothes on!?*

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Humanity had no shame of nakedness prior to Eve messing everything up because humanity wasn't naked until then, of course.  God took away our naturally-occurring clothing as part of the punishment.

Comment: Houston here. Texas has a great respect here for the Jesus, but it would be tremendously shocking if this was a picture of a Ted Cruz. Largely because I think he would have been drowned in a urinal by a good ole boy. Ted may as well put beans in his chili, turn up Empire State Of Mind, and stand on a track waiting for a "public transit" train to run him over. You got a better chance of finding Jeff Foxworthy birthing a kid with Clint Eastwood in a Mosque than passing mime-ry off as Texan.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - well the school and **mime** picture are evidently from Houston (whether it Ted or not) so your observation seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @HannoverFist I think you miss the point and I think that Evan perfectly makes the case about why this is a meme (whether it's Ted Cruz or not, this is exactly why this image is being used in this "meme fight"). It's not about whether there ARE mimes in Texas, or even at Ted Cruz's school, it's about "passing mimery off as" consistent with the Texan self-image. There IS beany chili available in Texas, too, you know, nobody's pretending there isn't, but does anyone try to "pass it off" as Texan chili?

Comment: @Beanluc not unless they want to die.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[The Daily Dot](https://www.dailydot.com/unclick/ted-cruz-high-school-mime-photo/) investigated this claim and found that the yearbook does in fact credit Ted Cruz as a mime Adam (and as you can see he is also barefoot):

> [image]
> Travis McWilliams, representing God and Ted Cruz as Adam act out the creation in a mime. Photo by M. Neath.

They also interviewed two classmates of Cruz's, Clint Rosenthal and the photographer of the picture "M. Neath":

> “I was in 5th grade and didn’t really know [Cruz],” recalled Clint Rosenthal, the tipster who sent the mime photo. “I assume I was in the audience since that appears to have been during Chapel. I guess I suppressed that memory.”
>
> “What I can say,” Rosenthal continued, “is that the biblical version of the creation of man (and ladies from Adam’s rib, etc.)—the subject of Cruz’s interpretive mime performance—was taught pretty literally there, so I’m betting a lot of folks in the audience were thinking he nailed it. Hell, it made the yearbook.”
>
> “M. Neath,” the person who took the photo, would surely know more. I found a smattering of search results for a Mark Neath, about Cruz’s age, and contacted him via email.
>
> “I was a classmate of Ted’s at Second Baptist School and a photographer on the yearbook staff, so I evidently did take the photo,” Neath wrote back. “I cannot confirm that it is Ted, but it certainly looks like him. The photo captions were pretty well-researched, and it was a very small school, so it would be surprising if it is wrong.”

Cruz eventually became [president of the drama club](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/feb/03/ted-cruz-high-school-teenager-yearbook-constitutional-corroborators), so he was definitely involved in theater.

Comment: It baffles me that anyone would go to the length of interviewing his former classmates to seek confirmation and background on his dramatic performances.

Comment: @Richard It baffles you that anyone does investigative journalism?  Or the topic of that journalism?  The piece was written by Jay Hathaway and seems right in his wheelhouse: "Jay Hathaway is a former senior writer who specialized in internet memes and weird online culture. He previously served as the Daily Dot’s news editor, was a staff writer at Gawker, and edited the classic websites Urlesque and Download Squad. His work has also appeared on nymag.com, suicidegirls.com, and the Morning News. "

Comment: @ttbek - This isn't investigative journalism, it's chasing people's childhood friends and asking them stupid questions.

Comment: @Richard It became politically relevant to know the answers to those questions.  This is exactly investigative journalism, to investigate and find the answers to these questions.  That will involve tracking people down and asking them questions.  I don't understand why you think doing something that is part of investigative journalism excludes this from being investigative journalism.  Do you hate on all investigative journalism or just when the topic of it seems irrelevant, or even politically inconvenient, to you?

Comment: I'm a Brit so I could care less if he was a mime in his high school play or the dead horse in Equus.

Comment: Wait, this guy did investigative journalism for a porn site? Now it all becomes clear.